# Probability and Statistics Expected Weekly Loss

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I have this exercise (picture below) and I have the mean calculated and the variance of the  random variable X, so I'm left with the formula for Loss, should I simplu substitute the X in the E(10X + 200) with the value of E(X) below? (1.904) in which case it would be 219.04.

Same for the variance?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the expectation of $aX+b$ is $aE(X)+b$ and the variance of $aX+b$ is $a^2$ times the variance of $X$.

**Remark:** I suggest recomputing $E(X)$ and $\text{Var}(X)$.

Comment: Yes I know the E(X) is wrong :P I did it myself and was amazed that there is such a mistake!!! :P
Thank you very much for your answer! :)

Comment: You are welcome. Numerical slips are hard to avoid. Software doesn't help a whole lot, mistakes of arithmetic get replaced by keying errors.